# Flora and fauna from a darker, foggy planet

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-earth

In a [previous post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125559/a-darker-foggy-planet), I consulted about the characteristics that a earth-like planet could have, if it's covered by a permanent mega-fog, with a chemical composition similar to water vapor, which slightly dissiminates the solar luminosity.

In [another post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/designing-a-mega-fog?noredirect=1&lq=1), I consulted about the conditions that would have originated this mega-fog.

Now is the time to consult about the flora and fauna that could develop in an environment like this. **What changes could the species of our planet experience under the conditions I propose?**

Comment: It might be more valuable to separate plants and animals.  Plants have a lot to do with light, but animals have a lot to do with plants.  Thus, plants first.  Also, note that (as I recall) more ultraviolet penetrates fog than infrared.  That's going to shift the absorbtion patterns of the plants a bit.

Comment: What changes could this cause in plants?

Comment: *"What changes could the species of our planet experience under the conditions I propose?"* You mean somebody transplanted terrestrial species of animals and plants to this soggy planet, and now they are waiting to see how they cope?

Comment: Coloration, for one thing.  It likely also changes the efficienciy of photosynthesis since you have a little high-energy light rather than a lot of mid-range energy light.  My guess is it would be a lot like the floor of a rainforest (with more fog).  You'll have a lot of low-light tolerant orchid and bromeliad type plants.  Ferns. etc.

Comment: @JBH: Terrestrial plants are green, which means that they *don't* absorb green, which is smack in the middle of the spectrum.

Comment: @AlexP, Let's advocate patience, Alex.  Jano's starting form a known condition and trying to extrapolate and unknown.  Inventing an entirely new biome would be too broad.  Also, while most terrestrial plants are green, many are not.  And, the most commonly absorbed spectrum is blue.  Shifting this up would likely produce more reflected reds.  (oooh... red + green means more brilliant yellows.  I like yellow... but you'd also see more purples than you do in Earth plants)

Comment: @JBH: My question is serious. It's one thing to ask how terrestrial plants would adapt to perpetual high humidity, and a *very different* thing to ask how plants which evolved in perpetual fog would look like. So, I really believe that my question ought to be answered. Note that I glossed over the *"chemical composition similar to water vapor"*.

Comment: Wait! Why are you asking for the conditions of the plants if you havent even recognized the composition of your fog? Do take note that a normal fog is highly beneficial for plants, but a vulcanic ash fog or a highly polluted fog due to coal fire are another story.

Comment: @AlexP No. 
I start from the premise that a planet similar to the Earth should have, in simple terms, a flora and fauna similar to ours. As JBH writes, the idea is to extrapolate an ecosystem like ours to an imaginary situation (e.g. mega-fog), so the idea of ​​"transplanting" species is not exactly correct.

Comment: @Mr.J: 
I think I have made it clear in previous posts that the idea of ​​volcanic ash, although it was plausible, was not original enough, in strictly literary terms. Now, I imagine that the mist of water vapor is beneficial for the vegetation, but at a massive level, it can lead to more complex changes and transformations.

Comment: Please, include all details needed to answer directly in this question. Linking to previous question is OK, but it should work only as a supplement, not as mandatory reading.